# How to store jQuery multiple values into php $_SESSION

Tags: php, jquery

I am using readymade modalbox which has three step process, in second step there is multiple checkboxes where user can choose two or more. Now I am confuse that how to pass this selected checkbox values to next step in modalbox.

```js
<script>
$('input[name=sweater]').change(function() {
    $('#area').val(
        $('[name=sweater]:checked').map(function() {
            return $(this).val();
        }).get().join(',')
   );
});
</script>
```

```html
<!-----------------------------------------First Step------------------------------------------------>
<div id="dialog_content" class="dialog_content" style="display:none">
 <div class="dialogModal_header">Dialog header 1</div>
 <div class="dialogModal_content">

        <?php
         $query1="select * from `usersweater` where `Sweaterid`='$sweaterid'";
         $result1=mysql_query($query1);
         $row1=mysql_fetch_assoc($result1);
         $sweaternikname=$row1['SNickname'];
        //echo $sweaternikname; 
     ?>
       <div>
          <ul class="sweaters">
              <li> 
                  <h4><?php echo $sweaternikname; ?></h4> 
                  <img src="upload/<?php echo $opic; ?>" style="width:100px; height:100px;" > 
              </li>
           </ul>
       </div>
      <input type="hidden" name="sweaterownerid" value="<?php echo $sownerid; ?>">
      <input type="hidden" name="osweaterpic" value="<?php echo $opic; ?>">
      <input type="hidden" name="osweaterid" value="<?php echo $sweaterid; ?>">                                       
      <h4>Are you sure you want to swap ? </h4>
      <br><br>
   </div>
    <div class="dialogModal_footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dialogmodal-but="next">Yes</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"data-dialogmodal-but="cancel">Continue Looking</button>
    </div>
</div>

<!-----------------------------------/first step over-------------------------->
<!-----------------------------------------Second Step------------------------------------------------>

                                                                             <?php
     
     $query1="select * from `usersweater` where `Sweaterid`='$sweaterid'";
     $result1=mysql_query($query1);
     $row1=mysql_fetch_assoc($result1);
     $sweaternikname=$row1['SNickname'];
     //echo $sweaternikname; 
     ?>
<div id="dialog_content2" class="dialog_content" style="display:none">
 <div class="dialogModal_header">Dialog header 2</div>
 <div class="dialogModal_content" style="min-height:400px;">
  
                                 <form action="" method="post">


        <div>
      <ul class="sweaters">
      <li> <h4><?php echo $sweaternikname; ?></h4> <img src="upload/<?php echo $opic; ?>" style="width:100px;"> </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="sweater1">
                                                                                         <?php
           $query="select * from `usersweater` where `Userid`='$userid' && `Swap`='0' ";
                  $result = mysql_query($query);
           while ($line = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
           $sid = $line[Sweaterid];
           $img = $line[Sweaterpic];
                  $nikname = $line[SNickname];
            $size = $line[Size];
              ?>
<li> <h4><?php echo $nikname; ?><input type="checkbox" name="sweater" value="<?php echo $sid; ?>" /></h4> <img src="upload/<?php echo $img; ?>" style="width:100px;"> </li>
      <?php  } ?>
      </ul>
     </div>

</div>

<input type="text" id="area">

 <div class="dialogModal_footer">
                <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Next" />
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dialogmodal-but="next">Next</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"data-dialogmodal-but="cancel">Cancel</button>
 </div>
 </div>
</form>
<!-----------------------------------------Second Step Over------------------------------------------------>
<!-----------------------------------------Third Step ----------------------------------------------->

<div id="dialog_content3" class="dialog_content" style="display:none">
 <div class="dialogModal_header">Dialog header 3</div>
 <div class="dialogModal_content" style="min-height:400px;">
      
 <!-----here i want to print that value------>
      
      
 </div>
 <div class="dialogModal_footer">
< id="area">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-left" data-dialogmodal-but="prev">Back</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dialogmodal-but="ok">Ok</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"data-dialogmodal-but="cancel">Cancel</button>
 </div>
</div>

<!-----------------------------------------Third Step Over----------------------------------------------->
```

In code  is the part where jQuery prints the values of selected checkboxes but how to pass? I try form but not successful. How to pass value not form action/href. I think session possible but no idea how to do. Put big code for understanding flow of modalbox.

Comment: Are you getting all the checked values from all the three steps? and where have you stored it currently?

Comment: yup....not stored but it print in text box seperated by comma

Answer (score 1):

With each step, when ever the user clicks on the checkbox, store the values in a `JS` object

```
var values={}; //createing a values object
$('.checkbox').change(function(){
 if($(this).is(':checked')){
    var checkboxvalue = $(this).val();
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
   values[id] = checkboxvalue;  //keep storing all infos in the object
}
});
```

Then when the user atlast clicks on submit button pass all the info via `AJAX`

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: addPackagePath,
  data: {allinfo : values}
  dataType: 'html',
  success: function(result){
  //do whatever you want
  }
});
```

Then after recieving all the infos from server end, store it in the `$_SESSION` variables

Answer (score 0):

As long as there is no page reload between the steps and you just show / hide parts of the page there is no need to use sessions. Just store it in a javascript variable like so

```
var sweater_val = $('[name=sweater]:checked').val();
```

Comment: how to store all selected values into mysql by this.?

Comment: When you're done with the modal just use jQuery.post() and call the PHP script that stores all the values. This script should be like a little API that also can validate the users input and return error messages or a success code which in turn can be used by your javascript modal to display feedback to the user. Check this tutorial: https://scotch.io/tutorials/submitting-ajax-forms-with-jquery